# Next JS routing for category and optional subcategory

Tags: next.js, url-routing

Trying to wrap my head around Next routing with an optional subcategory.

I have:

`/[category]/[item].js` which satisfies `/pizza/four-seasons` (and everything else under `pizza`)

I'd like to also have:

`/[category]/[subcategory]/[item.js]` to satisfy `/pizza/traditional/four-seasons` (and everything else that falls under `/pizza/traditional`)

Is this even possible?

Comment: That is possible, you should look into [dynamic catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes), e.g. `/[category]/[...item].js`.